# Cannot connect to remote Queue with @JmsListener

Tags: spring-boot, jms

I need to create a JMS Listener (annotations are preferred) to receive a message from a remote queue.   I started [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) with the tutorial on spring.io.

It was simple example with just an application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}

@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Launch the application
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

    System.out.println("Sending a message.");
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("mailbox", "someString");
}

}
```

and a receiver:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received message:" + message);
}

}
```

This worked fine.  The next step was to adapt the listener to receive from a remote queue.  We are using Tibco Jms and I replaced the Connection Factory in the bean with TibjmsConnectionFactory, supplied the url, username, password and a client ID. and in the destination field of the @JmsListener I put the queueName of the remote queue and supplied the containerFactory bean as well.  However, when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination <queueName' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Invalid protocol specification
```

if I comment out the listener I get no errors

I cannot see what I am missing

Comment: Any news about thus topic?